# how can we implement video calling in nativescript?

Tags: angular, voip, nativescript

I have to develop an android application in Nativescript. In which I have to provide option to the users to call to a specific user (call can be video or audio).
How to implement Video Calling in NativeScript?
can anyone please help in term of suggesting some protocol etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the easiest way to achieve that is to use 3rd party SDK for video calls like [Sinch!](https://www.sinch.com/downloads/) and either [create a NativeScript plugin](http://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugins) or directly use the ***.aar** and following the data conversion techniques to implement the logic to your NativeScript application.

Comment: Very basic concept for creating a Sinch plugin for NativeScript can be found here: https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-sinch

Comment: can we test this in our development phase ? means on emulator ?
Actually I am new to Nativescript so sorry for the odd questions.

Comment: The instant messages works great on emulators (tested the sample native app from Sinch's demos) .. however not sure about the video calls (the native demo is crashing on my side and I saw that it is in still in beta)